# ambiguous reference to member animate

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I use this code in viewDidAppear method

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0,5, delay: 0.5,
               usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0,
               options: [], animations: {
                self.loginButton.alpha = CGFloat(1.0)
}
                , completion: nil)
```

in the picture below I have a problem which I can't fix

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE0T9.png)

Comment: You have used , instead of . in 0.5 in first argument.

Comment: Thanks! Silly mistake

Comment: Replace withDuration: 0,5 with withDuration: 0.5. dot instead of ","

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Little mistake `withDuration` parameter 0,5 would be  0.5.